crc32 different output on kernelmode driver and usermode in c
unsigned __int32 GetCrc32(char* data, int length)
{
    unsigned __int32 r = 0xFFFFFFFFUL;
    int i, b;

    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        r ^= data[i];
        for (b = 0; b < 8; ++b)
        {
            if ((unsigned __int8)r & 1)
                r = (r >> 1) ^ 0xEDB88320UL;
            else
                r >>= 1;
        }
    }

    return r ^ 0xFFFFFFFFUL;
}

I receive different results when run this crc32 function in kernelmode for string: UFZND01ZR85O5E
From kernelmode driver compiled in WINDDK 7600.16385.1 I get the value: 8C0174D7
While in usermode compiled in SDK 10.0.22621.0 I get the value: 82087FAB
Can you tell me why please?

Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. There might be differences in how you pass the string or print the result. (To avoid possible sign extension, it might be good to use unsigned char *data instead of char with implementation-dependent signedness. Not sure if this can be relevant here.)

Please show how you call that function and how you print the result in both user mode and kernel mode.

Why are you using pre-standard integer types from the 1990s instead of stdint.h?

Anyway, it seems likely that the bug is in the calling code.

@Lundin it's most likely the built-in types of the Microsoft C compiler.

@Jabberwocky So? Stick to standard C.

Add some prints and you will know where the problem starts.

When I change your code to modern types it prints 82087fab.  Any other output is likely due to calling with a different string or length.

82087FAB is the correct CRC for "UFZND01ZR85O5E". The problem is somewhere in the calling code of your kernel driver or whatever. Most likely  the parameters you pass to the GetCrc32 function are not what you thing they are. You need to provide more information.

https://github.com/sherpya/nloader/blob/master/libs/ntdll/crc32.c kernel (in latest windows ) export both RtlComputeCrc32 and RtlCrc32

A possible cause of your problem is data has type char *, hence on architectures where char is signed by default, data[i] is sign extended before conversion to uint32_t, causing the step r ^= data[i] to produce an incorrect value.
Try this modified version:
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t GetCrc32(unsigned char *data, size_t length)
{
    uint32_t r = 0xFFFFFFFFUL;
    size_t i, b;

    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        r ^= data[i];
        for (b = 0; b < 8; ++b)
        {
            if (r & 1)
                r = (r >> 1) ^ 0xEDB88320UL;
            else
                r >>= 1;
        }
    }
    return ~r;
}


As far as I understood, the OP is using Windows and I doubt that the signedness is different between compiling for kernel mode and user mode.

I've tested the function [as a linux app] with both signed char * and unsigned char * and there is no difference: 82087FAB. So, as Jabberwocky says in the top comments, it is probably the caller (in the kernel) that is doing something funky.

@Jabberwocky: I don't know what the default char signedness is in Windows, but that must depend on the compiler and its options.  It is best to avoid replying on any particular char signedness for any code.  If the prototype cann ot be changed, at least change the line r ^= data[i]; to r ^= (unsigned char)data[i];

@CraigEstey: you might get the same result for both signed char *data and unsigned char *data if the buffer contains only bytes without the high bit set or in some more obscure specific circumstances.  Try computing the checksum for a single byte with value 0xff: GetCrc32 should return 0xFF for unsigned char * and 0xFFFFFFFF for signed char *.

Found this code works ok:
static unsigned long Crc32_ComputeBuf(const void* buf, size_t bufLen) {
    static const unsigned long crcTable[256] = {
     0x00000000,0x77073096,0xEE0E612C,0x990951BA,0x076DC419,0x706AF48F,0xE963A535,
     0x9E6495A3,0x0EDB8832,0x79DCB8A4,0xE0D5E91E,0x97D2D988,0x09B64C2B,0x7EB17CBD,
     0xE7B82D07,0x90BF1D91,0x1DB71064,0x6AB020F2,0xF3B97148,0x84BE41DE,0x1ADAD47D,
     0x6DDDE4EB,0xF4D4B551,0x83D385C7,0x136C9856,0x646BA8C0,0xFD62F97A,0x8A65C9EC,
     0x14015C4F,0x63066CD9,0xFA0F3D63,0x8D080DF5,0x3B6E20C8,0x4C69105E,0xD56041E4,
     0xA2677172,0x3C03E4D1,0x4B04D447,0xD20D85FD,0xA50AB56B,0x35B5A8FA,0x42B2986C,
     0xDBBBC9D6,0xACBCF940,0x32D86CE3,0x45DF5C75,0xDCD60DCF,0xABD13D59,0x26D930AC,
     0x51DE003A,0xC8D75180,0xBFD06116,0x21B4F4B5,0x56B3C423,0xCFBA9599,0xB8BDA50F,
     0x2802B89E,0x5F058808,0xC60CD9B2,0xB10BE924,0x2F6F7C87,0x58684C11,0xC1611DAB,
     0xB6662D3D,0x76DC4190,0x01DB7106,0x98D220BC,0xEFD5102A,0x71B18589,0x06B6B51F,
     0x9FBFE4A5,0xE8B8D433,0x7807C9A2,0x0F00F934,0x9609A88E,0xE10E9818,0x7F6A0DBB,
     0x086D3D2D,0x91646C97,0xE6635C01,0x6B6B51F4,0x1C6C6162,0x856530D8,0xF262004E,
     0x6C0695ED,0x1B01A57B,0x8208F4C1,0xF50FC457,0x65B0D9C6,0x12B7E950,0x8BBEB8EA,
     0xFCB9887C,0x62DD1DDF,0x15DA2D49,0x8CD37CF3,0xFBD44C65,0x4DB26158,0x3AB551CE,
     0xA3BC0074,0xD4BB30E2,0x4ADFA541,0x3DD895D7,0xA4D1C46D,0xD3D6F4FB,0x4369E96A,
     0x346ED9FC,0xAD678846,0xDA60B8D0,0x44042D73,0x33031DE5,0xAA0A4C5F,0xDD0D7CC9,
     0x5005713C,0x270241AA,0xBE0B1010,0xC90C2086,0x5768B525,0x206F85B3,0xB966D409,
     0xCE61E49F,0x5EDEF90E,0x29D9C998,0xB0D09822,0xC7D7A8B4,0x59B33D17,0x2EB40D81,
     0xB7BD5C3B,0xC0BA6CAD,0xEDB88320,0x9ABFB3B6,0x03B6E20C,0x74B1D29A,0xEAD54739,
     0x9DD277AF,0x04DB2615,0x73DC1683,0xE3630B12,0x94643B84,0x0D6D6A3E,0x7A6A5AA8,
     0xE40ECF0B,0x9309FF9D,0x0A00AE27,0x7D079EB1,0xF00F9344,0x8708A3D2,0x1E01F268,
     0x6906C2FE,0xF762575D,0x806567CB,0x196C3671,0x6E6B06E7,0xFED41B76,0x89D32BE0,
     0x10DA7A5A,0x67DD4ACC,0xF9B9DF6F,0x8EBEEFF9,0x17B7BE43,0x60B08ED5,0xD6D6A3E8,
     0xA1D1937E,0x38D8C2C4,0x4FDFF252,0xD1BB67F1,0xA6BC5767,0x3FB506DD,0x48B2364B,
     0xD80D2BDA,0xAF0A1B4C,0x36034AF6,0x41047A60,0xDF60EFC3,0xA867DF55,0x316E8EEF,
     0x4669BE79,0xCB61B38C,0xBC66831A,0x256FD2A0,0x5268E236,0xCC0C7795,0xBB0B4703,
     0x220216B9,0x5505262F,0xC5BA3BBE,0xB2BD0B28,0x2BB45A92,0x5CB36A04,0xC2D7FFA7,
     0xB5D0CF31,0x2CD99E8B,0x5BDEAE1D,0x9B64C2B0,0xEC63F226,0x756AA39C,0x026D930A,
     0x9C0906A9,0xEB0E363F,0x72076785,0x05005713,0x95BF4A82,0xE2B87A14,0x7BB12BAE,
     0x0CB61B38,0x92D28E9B,0xE5D5BE0D,0x7CDCEFB7,0x0BDBDF21,0x86D3D2D4,0xF1D4E242,
     0x68DDB3F8,0x1FDA836E,0x81BE16CD,0xF6B9265B,0x6FB077E1,0x18B74777,0x88085AE6,
     0xFF0F6A70,0x66063BCA,0x11010B5C,0x8F659EFF,0xF862AE69,0x616BFFD3,0x166CCF45,
     0xA00AE278,0xD70DD2EE,0x4E048354,0x3903B3C2,0xA7672661,0xD06016F7,0x4969474D,
     0x3E6E77DB,0xAED16A4A,0xD9D65ADC,0x40DF0B66,0x37D83BF0,0xA9BCAE53,0xDEBB9EC5,
     0x47B2CF7F,0x30B5FFE9,0xBDBDF21C,0xCABAC28A,0x53B39330,0x24B4A3A6,0xBAD03605,
     0xCDD70693,0x54DE5729,0x23D967BF,0xB3667A2E,0xC4614AB8,0x5D681B02,0x2A6F2B94,
     0xB40BBE37,0xC30C8EA1,0x5A05DF1B,0x2D02EF8D
    };
    unsigned long inCrc32 = 0;
    unsigned long crc32;
    unsigned char* byteBuf;

    size_t i;

    /** accumulate crc32 for buffer **/
    crc32 = inCrc32 ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;
    byteBuf = (unsigned char*)buf;
    for (i = 0; i < bufLen; i++) {
        crc32 = (crc32 >> 8) ^ crcTable[(crc32 ^ byteBuf[i]) & 0xFF];
    }
    return crc32 ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

I'm sorry but don't understand what you are asking for. It is just a function that works the same in WINDDK 7600.16385.1  gives output 82087FAB and in SDK 10.0.22621.0 also the same value: 82087FAB.

@pulpf: the OP asks Can you tell me why please?. Providing code that works without an explanation does not answer the question: telling the OP what is wrong in the code is more helpful.  The implementation you posted does use an unsigned char *buf to access the data, which the OP's code does not, and it uses a global array to generate branchless optimized code, which is interesting albeit somewhat obscure. Also note that this code uses unsigned long instead of uint32_t, which could pose a problem on systems where long has 64 bits, but careful analysis of the code shows it works too.
